# Escaping From "/" Character in Dart Encryption

Tags: flutter, http, dart, post, encryption

I have an encryption class in Dart, which will encrypt User ID for posting it to MariaDB table with REST (Post Request, ? and * is placeholder, these are different in my real code.):

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
//import 'dart:convert' as convert;

    class Security {
      ///Key
      static final _key =
          Key.fromUtf8('********************************'); //32 chars
      static final iv = IV.fromUtf8('????????????????'); //16 chars
    
      ///encrypt, [text] is data.
      static String encryptMyData(String text) {
        final e = Encrypter(AES(_key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
        final encryptedData = e.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
        return encryptedData.base64;
      }
    
      ///decrypt, [text] is data.
      static String decryptMyData(String text) {
        final e = Encrypter(AES(_key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
        final decryptedData = e.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(text), iv: iv);
        return decryptedData;
      }
    }
```

Sometimes, "/" char coming in encrypted ID, which causes 404 and 405 errors on POST request. Because "/" is HTML routing character.

My POST code is:

```
///Adds an user item to database via decoding / encoding the JSON value.
///[name] is name, [surname] is surname, [uid] is user id, [type] is user role, [debt] is user debt, [paucode] is pay code.
  static Future<bool> addUserToDatabase(String name, String surname, String uid,
      double debt, String paycode, int type) async {
    try {
      if (name != null &&
          surname != null &&
          uid != null &&
          debt != null &&
          paycode != null &&
          type != null) {
        var addingUser = User(name.toLowerCase(), surname.toLowerCase(),
            Security.encryptMyData(uid), type, debt, paycode);

        print('This user will be added:\n------\n$addingUser\n-----------\n');

        var uri = Uri.https('localhost:5001',
            'User/username=${addingUser.userName}&surname=${addingUser.userSurname}&id=${addingUser.personID}&debt=${addingUser.userDebt}&type=${addingUser.type}&paycode=${addingUser.payCode}');
        print('The URI: $uri');
        var request = await http.post(uri);
        print(
            'The response:\n----\n- ${request.body}\n Status Code: ${request.statusCode}\n----\n');
        if (request.statusCode == 201 || request.statusCode == 200) {
          // If the server did return a 201 Created response,
          // then return value.
          return true;
        } else {
          // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
          // then throw an exception.
          throw Exception(
              'Failed to add user. Status Code: ${request.statusCode}');
        }
      }
      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print('An error occurred - $e');
      return false;
    }
  }
```

How I escaping from "/" character in Dart encryption ? I don't want this character in the encrypted string. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encryptMyData()` Base64 encodes the data. The [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) alphabet contains alphanumeric characters and the characters `/`, `+` and `=` (padding), where the last three have a special meaning and are therefore reserved in the context of [URIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Reserved_characters).

A simple way to mask these characters would be to URL encode the Base64 encoded strings with [`Uri.encodeComponent()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Uri/encodeComponent.html). Accordingly, URL decoding with [`Uri.decodeComponent()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Uri/decodeComponent.html) must be performed before Base64 decoding:

```
var base64Data = 'EBES/+7dzA==';
var urlEnc = Uri.encodeComponent(base64Data);
print(urlEnc); // EBES%2F%2B7dzA%3D%3D

// Apply in URL

var urlDec = Uri.decodeComponent(urlEnc);
print(urlDec); // EBES/+7dzA==
```

---

Alternatively, [Base64url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) can be applied instead of Base64. Base64url uses the characters `_` and `-` instead of `/` and `+` as well as *optional* padding. Unlike `/` and `+`, `_` and `-` are not reserved for URIs.

Base64url is supported in Dart by [`base64Url.encode()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-convert/base64UrlEncode.html). The padding is applied, but can be removed explicitly (e.g. with `replaceAll('=','')`). Decoding is possible with `base64Url.decode()` (after the padding has been added). Alternatively, [`base64Url.normalize()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-convert/Base64Codec/normalize.html) can be used to convert to Base64 (which automatically adds the padding) and `base64.decode()` can be applied for Base64 decoding:

```
var b64urlEnc = base64Url.encode([16, 17, 18, 255, 238, 221, 204]);// [0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0xff, 0xee, 0xdd, 0xcc]
print(b64urlEnc); // EBES_-7dzA==
var b64urlEncNoPadding = b64urlEnc.replaceAll('=','');
print(b64urlEncNoPadding); // EBES_-7dzA

// Apply in URL

var base64Enc = base64Url.normalize(b64urlEncNoPadding);
print(base64Enc); // EBES/+7dzA==
var base64Dec = base64.decode(base64Enc);
print(base64Dec); // [16, 17, 18, 255, 238, 221, 204]
```

Optionally, for already Base64 encoded data, the characters `/` and `+` can be replaced by `_` and `-` and the padding (`=`) can be removed.

Comment: Uri.encodeComponent() and Uri.decodeComponent() are suitable for me, thanks @Topaco